# Bone effecting part of mesh it has 0 influence on?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

though its my second time modeling, its my first time weight painting + working with mesh aspects particularly close to one another.

[image]

seen above the right arm bone has absolutely no influence to the belt-tail part of the mesh

[image]
however when the arm is moved in the pose menu it moves with it! any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

yes, on the object property panel (to your right) go to the tab where it shows a icon,triangle of vertices. Look for the Vertex group panel there.
You´ll see a list of "weight groups" you need to locate the one that is named exactly like the bone is afecting your tail. Once you find it, you´ll see your arm turns on with color (in your image is red) and then go to the T panel on your viewport (press T) and on the tool select SUBSTRACT brush. Place the settings to : 1 in weight. 1 in strenght. Now, paint the TAIL.

This will substract instantly every weight influence the tail is having from any other bone.

Once you´re done, switch back to DRAW in your tool palette.

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller